# How do I extract a list of services AND what account they run as?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-server-2003, windows-services

The emphasis of this question is on the second half.

I know how to extract a list of all the services and how to filter on their state. However, what I am unsure how to do is to extract the user account the service is set to "run as".

I don't have the option of using PowerShell (unfortunately) so I'm looking for a native CMD way. I assumed there would be a way to use the sc query command but all that lists is:

```
SERVICE_NAME
TYPE
STATE
WIN32_EXIT_CODE
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE
CHECKPOINT
WAIT_HINT
```

FYI - The OS is WIndows 2003  SP2 and I need this information for all of the services so is a long winded process if I have to do it manually for each of them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**wmic:**
Name and account for all services:
`wmic service get name,startname`

started services only:
`wmic service where started=true get  name, startname`

services with specific pattern in name:
`wmic service where 'name like "%sql%"' get  name, startname`

nicely formatted as html table (and then opened in your browser):
`(wmic service where 'name like "%sql%"' get  name, startname /format:htable >out.html) && out.html`

Full syntax here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What's the difference between `sc query` and `wmic`?

Comment: @Pacerier Difference in regards to what? They are just different (cmd line) tools allowing you to query/interact with services; sc is for this purpose only, while wmic is more general (as it allows one to query various parts of the system). wmic is also easier to use for this particular problem (only one query)

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this in two steps:

1. Get the list of services:`sc \\localhost query | findstr SERVICE_NAME`
2. Your missing piece: `sc \\localhost qc` + SERVICE_NAME +  `| findstr SERVICE_START_NAME`

I would recommend a batch script like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
sc \\localhost query | findstr SERVICE_NAME > services.lst
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (services.lst) do (
    echo %%B
    sc \\localhost qc %%B | findstr SERVICE_START_NAME
)
del services.lst
```

That gives you an output like this:
[image]

Of course, you can further cleanup that output or write to a CSV file in any manner that you would like.

Answer (score 1):

CMD has no native way to do it. SC and NET are built-in applications that come with Windows but that doesn't mean they're native. At any time an admin can remove them and then even CMD is left in the dark.

sc sdshow  is what will get you security descriptors, but this will complicate things if you don't know how to read SDDL strings.

Simplest way is to get Sysinternals PsService.exe from Tools package and use it as psservice security [service]. It will list the SDDL in readable format, including account names.

Comment: What do you mean by "no native way to do it"? Isn't it in `C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe` for all versions of windows?

Comment: Read again. Built-in means non-removable like CMD. If an admin disables PowerShell, then he can disable sc and net as well. Simplest way is to use a portable app that does all by default and is not tied to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't use PowerShell you should still be able to use VBScript to pull the info from WMI:

Here's a VBS script that will list all services and the account they start as:

```vbs
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Service")

For Each objService in colServices 
    wscript.echo objService.Name & ": " & objService.StartName
Next
```

Save it and then run it with `cscript ScriptName.vbs`.

`objService.State` would give you the service's current state (since you mentioned you're looking to filter by it).

More info on the [Win32_Service class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx).