# Internationalization of "sc" command

Tags: windows

We have an application that parses the output of `sc qdescription <service_name>` to get the service description, and the usual output is something like:

```
C:\>sc qdescription WSearch
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: WSearch
DESCRIPTION:  Provides content indexing, property caching, and search results for files, e-mail, and other content.
```

However, we just discovered that depending on the OS language, the output can be different, e.g. in German:

```
C:\>sc qdescription WSearch
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 ERFOLG

SERVICE_NAME: WSearch
BESCHREIBUNG:  Stellt Inhaltsindizierung und Eigenschaftenzwischenspeicherung und Suchergebnisse für Dateien, E-Mails und andere Inhalte bereit.
```

My question is:

- Which criteria should be used to extract the description? The second occurrence of the text after the `:`?
- What about other languages, e.g. Arabic or Chinese?

Comment: There are other ways, see [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/902809/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-services-and-what-account-they-run-as) Here a wmic query: `wmic service where Name='WSearch' get name,caption,description /format:csv` either parse the csv output directly or first save to a file.

Comment: @LotPings: thanks a lot, please post this as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, there are [other ways](https://superuser.com/questions/902809/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-services-and-what-account-they-run-as).

Using Service `Wuauserv` instead of `Wsearch`

A `wmic` query with output formatted as csv has the disadvantage that the values are **NOT** double quoted, so parsing get's difficult when the description also contains commas.

```
wmic service where Name='Wuauserv' get name,caption,description /format:csv
```

The object oriented powershell doesn't have this problem:

```
(Get-Wmiobject win32_service | Where Name -eq 'Wuauserv').Description
```

The same wrapped into a batch file:

```
@Echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%A in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(get-wmiobject win32_service|Where Name -eq 'Wuauserv').Description"
`) do set "Description=%%A"
set Description
```

Sample output (German locale)

> >set Description
>   Description=Erkennung, Herunterladen und Installation von Updates für Windows und andere Programme. Wenn der Dienst deaktiviert ist, können "Windows Update" bzw. das Feature "automatische Updates" nicht verwendet werden. Außerdem können Programme
>    dann die Windows Update Agent-Programmierschnittstelle (WUA API) nicht verwenden.