# How can I export the list of all my services with their path to executable on Microsoft Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, export, windows-services

How can I export the list of all my services with their path to executable on Microsoft Windows 7?

Example of  path to executable for a Windows service:

[image]

The default "export list" doesn't contain the paths to executable:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract a list of services AND what account they run as?](https://superuser.com/questions/902809/how-do-i-extract-a-list-of-services-and-what-account-they-run-as)

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, which parameter should I give to wmic to get the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I export the list of all my services with their paths on Microsoft Windows 7?

```
wmic service get name, pathname
```

Example output (truncated):

```
F:\test>wmic service get name, pathname
Name                            PathName



!SASCORE                        "C:\apps\SuperAntiSpyware\SASCORE64.EXE"



ACDaemon                        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcSoft\Connection Service\Bin\ACService.exe



AdobeARMservice                 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\ARM\1.0\armsvc.exe"



AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc       C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerUpdateService.exe



AeLookupSvc                     C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs



ALG                             C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe



AppIDSvc                        C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceAndNoImpersonation



Appinfo                         C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k netsvcs



Apple Mobile Device Service     "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\AppleMobileDeviceService.exe"



aspnet_state                    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_state.exe



aswbIDSAgent                    "C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswidsagent.exe"



Atheros Bt&Wlan Coex Agent      C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite\Ath_CoexAgent.exe
```